# Configuring UIImagePickerController so that the user can "Add a caption" in the Preview Screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Some apps display an "Add a caption" in the Preview Screen after taking/selecting an Image using UIImagePickerController. How do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iPhone OS 3.1 and later you can manage the camera interactions yourself, if desired. You can provide a custom overlay view to display a custom picture-taking interface and you can initiate the taking of pictures from your code. Your custom overlay view can be displayed in addition to, or instead of, the default controls provided by the image picker interface.

To use this class, you must provide a delegate that conforms to the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol. After the interface starts, this class notifies your delegate of the user’s actions. Your delegate is then responsible for dismissing the picker and returning to your application’s views. For more information about this protocol, see UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Protocol Reference.

See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html